# Does anyone know why my this code is not running? When I click the submit button it does nothing?If anyone might have an idea?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

When I click the send button of my contact form nothing happens on blogger

Anyone can help? it would be a great help?

```html
<div dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;" trbidi="on">
  <div dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;" trbidi="on">
    <br /></div>
  <script>
    var blogId = '#';
    //The below message 5 Strings can also be edited
    var contactFormMessageSendingMsg = 'Sending...';
    var contactFormMessageSentMsg = 'Your message has been sent.';
    var contactFormMessageNotSentMsg = 'Message could not be sent. Please try again later.';
    var contactFormEmptyMessageMsg = 'Message field cannot be empty.';
    var contactFormInvalidEmailMsg = 'A valid email is required.'

    var widgetLoaded = false;

    function sendEmailMsg() {
      if (widgetLoaded == false) {
        _WidgetManager._RegisterWidget('_ContactFormView', new _WidgetInfo('ContactForm1', 'sidebar',
          null, document.getElementById('ContactForm1'), {
            'contactFormMessageSendingMsg': contactFormMessageSendingMsg,
            'contactFormMessageSentMsg': contactFormMessageSentMsg,
            'contactFormMessageNotSentMsg': contactFormMessageNotSentMsg,
            'contactFormInvalidEmailMsg': contactFormInvalidEmailMsg,
            'contactFormEmptyMessageMsg': contactFormEmptyMessageMsg,
            'title': 'Contact Form',
            'blogId': blogId,
            'contactFormNameMsg': 'Name',
            'contactFormEmailMsg': 'Email',
            'contactFormMessageMsg': 'Message',
            'contactFormSendMsg': 'Send',
            'submitUrl': 'https://www.blogger.com/contact-form.do'
          }, 'displayModeFull'));
        widgetLoaded = true;
        document.getElementById('ContactForm1_contact-form-submit').click();
      }
      return true;
    }
  </script>


  <br />
  <form name="contact-form">
    <div>
      Your Name : </div>
    <input class="contact-form-name" id="ContactForm1_contact-form-name" name="name" size="30" type="text" value="" />

    <br />
    <div>
      Your Email: <em>(required)</em></div>
    <input class="contact-form-email" id="ContactForm1_contact-form-email" name="email" size="30" type="text" value="" />

    <br />
    <div>
      Your Message: <em>(required)</em></div>
    <textarea class="contact-form-email-message" id="ContactForm1_contact-form-email-message" name="email-message" rows="5"></textarea> By creating an account you agree to our <a href="https://notifyhands.blogspot.com/p/terms- 
                    and-conditions-last-updated-july.html">Terms &amp; Conditions</a>.<br />
    <input class="contact-form-button contact-form-button-submit" id="ContactForm1_contact-form- 
                    submit" onclick="sendEmailMsg()" type="submit" value="Send" />

    <br />
    <div style="max-width: 450px; text-align: center; width: 100%;">
      <div class="contact-form-error-message" id="ContactForm1_contact-form-error-message">
      </div>
      <div class="contact-form-success-message" id="ContactForm1_contact-form-success-message">
      </div>
    </div>

  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there some error in console? (On Google Chrome press F12 and check console tab, or google how to open Developer Tools on your browser)

Comment: What is `_WidgetManager`?